# USB ESD Protection with the NUF2042XV6T1G IC

Tags: circuit-design, protection, usb-device, esd

I have been trying to figure out how exactly I should connect the NUF2042XV6T1G IC to my USB data lines. From what I understand, usually a reverse biased transile diode is connected between the data lines and either the ground or the shell. My question is, how would I connect this specific IC to protect the circuit against ESD? I was thinking of "passing" the data lines "through" the IC, but I don't think that is the intended way - though seeing as how this IC is not very widely used (but somehow the only ESD protection IC my supplier sells) I could not find any example schematics. The image below shows the IC from the [datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/nuf2030xv6-d.pdf). I am also curious whether I must use ESD protection for the CH340G ic or not, since a lot of designs seem to omit it.

[image: IC]

And here's how I was planning on using it.
[image: Schematic]

Thanks in advance.